# RS FORM in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, forms, joomla

We are building a new Joomla 3.4.3 website with RS FORM Pro for creating forms.

I have created a custom HTML module with a boostrap button to open a RS Form in a Modal. The modal opens perfectly with the correct RS FORM but the thank you message will not be shown in the modal directly. You have to press the bootstrap button to see it (also when you have entered wrong information and didn't pass the validation).

The code i have used:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal --> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md"
type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#koffie"> Maak een afspraak 
</button> <!-- Modal -->
<div id="koffie" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data- 
dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Afspraak inplannen</h4>
<div class="modal-body">{rsform 7}</div>
```

I found some additional code which I have included in the custom HMTL page which should solve this but it now opens the form directly when you visit our main homepage, which shouldn't happen. What have i done wrong?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#koffie').modal();
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: your question is not clear please elaborate. and please create a fiddle..

Comment: The fiddle has been created https://jsfiddle.net/k8o6xbo1/ I need a form to be opened via a bootstrap button -> open a bootstrap modal - display a RS FORM FORM id 4 - This all works as expected - After submitting the data in the RS FORM the modal closes and doesn't show the "thank you message of RS FORMS - this will be displayed when you press the Bootstrap BTN BTN primary button again. - I found the Java code to prevent the closure of the Bootstrap modal so that the thank you message is presented in the current modal but that doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: is it important to show error message on the model itself? can't you show thank you message on the main page where your "Open a bootstrap modal" button is placed. so ideally when user open the popup, fill the form, submit the form; The model gets closed and depending on the response from server you show your thank you message on the main page.

Comment: In current scenario, submit form is triggering an action that's preventing it from showing your thank you message.

Comment: @Dirk_R did you ever find a solution for this, I am running into the same problem.